Need to replace delimited string with values from another table
I have two tables, and need to replace values in a pipe-delimited string with values from another table, using a single query.
create table a( col1 Varchar2(100), col2 Varchar2(250));   
insert into a values ('EMP', '1234|5678|9123');   

create table b ( col1 Varchar2(100), col2 Varchar2(250));  
insert into b values (1234 , 'Testing1');
insert into b values (5678, 'Values2');
insert into b values (9123 , 'Agree1');

I want a single query which provides output:



Col1
Col2




EMP
Testing1|Values2|Agree1




Perhaps better ways, but you might be able to use a CTE to split your string into rows, then use a 2nd CTE to join to table B for getting your replacement values, and then have a query against the 2nd CTE which uses LISTAGG() to put it back together.

Never, ever store data like that. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Would you ever have more than one row with the same Col1 value?

You can use a LATERAL join to a row generator to split the data into rows and then join to table b and aggregate to recombine the values:
SELECT a.col1, c.*
FROM   a
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(b.col2, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY position) AS value
         FROM   (
                  SELECT LEVEL AS position,
                         REGEXP_SUBSTR(col2, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) AS value
                  FROM   DUAL
                  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(col2, '[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
                ) v
                INNER JOIN b
                ON (v.value = b.col1)
       ) c

Which, for the sample data:
create table a( col1 Varchar2(100), col2 Varchar2(250));   
create table b ( col1 Varchar2(100), col2 Varchar2(250));  

insert into a values ('EMP1', '1234|5678|9123');
insert into a values ('EMP2', '9123|9123');
insert into b values (1234 , 'Testing1');
insert into b values (5678, 'Values2');
insert into b values (9123 , 'Agree1');

Outputs:



COL1
VALUE




EMP1
Testing1|Values2|Agree1


EMP2
Agree1|Agree1



fiddle

Upvoted as this solution also works if the same tableA.col1 value can appear in multiple rows.

In the absence of a working fiddle in the question, I have created two common table expressions (a and b) to create the data.  Then it splits the strings from a, joins to b, and aggregates the list back into a delimited string.
sortorder may not be needed.  I didn't take the time to read if Oracle guarantees that REGEXP_SUBSTR and LISTAGG return the values in the order you expect.
I use DISTINCT to get one row per col1 value.
See the fiddle
with
a ( 
    col1
  , col2
) as (
  select 'EMP', '1234|5678|9123' from dual
), 
b (
    col1
  , col2
) as (
        select 1234, 'Testing1' from dual
  union select 5678, 'Values2'  from dual
  union select 9123, 'Agree1'   from dual
), 
c as (
  select 
    col1
  , regexp_substr(col2, '[^|]+', 1, level) as col2
  from a
  connect by regexp_substr(col2, '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
), 
d as (
  select 
    c.col1
  , b.col2
  , row_number() over (partition by c.col1 order by 1) as sortorder
  from c
    inner join b on b.col1 = c.col2
)
select distinct 
  col1
, listagg(col2, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sortorder) over (partition by col1) AS col2
from d

This assumes the output should always have only one row per a.col1 value.
